# Search.execute() Youtube API won't work

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm writing a simple Youtube application for personal proposes..
The code won't work, after Search.execute() the app 'working' but not doing anything.
This is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.*;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ResourceId;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class fYoutube extends Fragment{
    /*Global Variables*/
    static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS = 10; // To show only 10 videos at a time.
//    static final String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "youtube.properties";
    private YouTube youTube;
    ImageView imageView;
    String apiKey = "AIzaSyD47jgw5kPCDUOoAvWPs-4jLFGW6ZinYrI";
    public fYoutube() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void getQuery(String query){
        if (query.length()<1) query="Youtube"; // Default search word is 'Youtube'.
        try {
            youTube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name)).build();
            YouTube.Search.List search = youTube.search().list("id,snippet");


            search.setKey(apiKey);
            search.setQ(query); //What to search for.
            search.setType("video");
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
            search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS);

            SearchListResponse searchListResponse = search.execute(); << After this line, the app won't do anything..
            List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchListResponse.getItems();
            displayThumbnails(searchResultList.iterator(),query);

           // if(searchResultList!=null){

  //          }
        }catch(IOException e){}

    }

    public void displayThumbnails(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults, String query){
        if(!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()){ Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No results for: "+query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        while(iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()){
            SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
            ResourceId resourceId = singleVideo.getId();
            if(resourceId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")){
                try {
                    String img_url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + resourceId + "/default.jpg";
                    imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.thumbnail1);
                    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(img_url).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(imageView);
                }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to do..
No logcat added because the app does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

So when you call search.execute(), you are returning a SearchListResponse. The app does nothing after that because you are not telling the app to do something with the returned value.

You need to do something with that SearchListResponse.
So you should uncomment the lines below search.execute().